# fill some Textbox with user name

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a problem with chrome, when I login in to my app and move between pages chrome fill some input type='text' with usernames saved in chrome automatically. I think it's for new version of chrome, How to prevent of it? Is there a html attribute that prevent of it?

Answer (score 0):

**Turning Off Autofill in Chrome**

Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three dots at top right of screen.)

Click on Settings.

In the "Autofill" section, expand the area for which you wish to disable Autofill.

Toggle the setting OFF if it is on.  The system will automatically save your settings.

**Clearing Autofill Data in Chrome**

Click the Chrome menu icon. (Three dots at top right of screen.)

Click on History, then click on History again in the menu that appears.

Select Clear browsing data.

At the top, choose “the beginning of time” option to clear all saved data.

Make sure that the “Clear saved Autofill form data” option is checked.

Click Clear browsing data.

Comment: I want doesn't allow it happened for anybody that login in my web application.On the other hand with  you solution google chrome doesn't fill all my textbox even my login form

Answer (score 0):

Try to use  `autocomplete` attribute

```
autocomplete="off"
```

**Example** : `<input type="text" name="username" autocomplete="off">`